# query to find the athlete with the most medals per year in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select A."ID","ATHLETE_NAME", "YEAR" 
from OLYM."OLYM_ATHLETES" A 
JOIN OLYM."OLYM_MEDALS" B ON A."ID" = B."ATHLETE_GAME_ID" 
JOIN OLYM."OLYM_GAMES" C ON B."EVENT_ID" = C.ID;
```

this gave me a table with athlete id, name and year in which he won a medal. is there any way to extract the highest decorated athlete per year form this table or am i missing something?

[Table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcBkj.jpg)

Comment: Hello MusteredBlaster, next time you post a question, please *type out* the create table statement and the dml statement to insert some data instead of posting a picture. That makes it a lot simpler for the contributors on this site to create an answer based on your data.

Answer (score 1):

If I followed you correctly, you need the athlete with max award in a year. If this is what you required then you can use the analytical function `row_number` as follows:

```
SELECT ID, ATHLETE_NAME, YEAR, CNT FROM
(select A."ID","ATHLETE_NAME", "YEAR", COUNT(1) AS cnt,
       Row_number() over (partition by "YEAR" order by count(1) desc) as rn
from OLYM."OLYM_ATHLETES" A 
JOIN OLYM."OLYM_MEDALS" B ON A."ID" = B."ATHLETE_GAME_ID" 
JOIN OLYM."OLYM_GAMES" C ON B."EVENT_ID" = C.ID
group by A."ID","ATHLETE_NAME", "YEAR")
WHERE RN = 1
ORDER BY YEAR
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query, this query will provide you the count of an athlete. You can use `HAVING` clause further to filter out according to your requirement

```
select A."ID","ATHLETE_NAME", "YEAR", count(1) 
from OLYM."OLYM_ATHLETES" A 
JOIN OLYM."OLYM_MEDALS" B ON A."ID" = B."ATHLETE_GAME_ID" 
JOIN OLYM."OLYM_GAMES" C ON B."EVENT_ID" = C.ID
group by A."ID","ATHLETE_NAME", "YEAR" order by count(1) desc;
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick reply but I dont understand how this helps me. did you check the image i attached? there you see the result of my query. what i need is to extract further from that table the amount of times each athlete won a medal within the same year. if its even possible to do that from within that table.